# Azure Active Directory workload is not enabled for rich notifications

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to create a subscription in Azure AD for receiving notification when a user is deleted. But I receive a 400 response code, and a message "Azure Active Directory workload is not enabled for rich notifications". I don't know the reason. what do I have to do ?!

here is my request :

```js
{
  "changeType": "deleted",
  "notificationUrl": "https://95bb3cee58yb.ngrok.io/azure/notifications",
  "resource": "users",
  "includeResourceData": true,
  "expirationDateTime": "2020-09-30T10:27:03.4541718Z",
  "clientState": "secretClientValue",
  "latestSupportedTlsVersion": "v1_2"
}
```

and here is the response :

```js
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidRequest",
    "message": "Azure Active Directory workload is not enabled for rich notifications.",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2020-09-28T13:05:26",
      "request-id": "ba715410-16a2-480f-840b-e72e863c4a05",
      "client-request-id": "577c315b-8715-753c-4efd-68a4729b92c2"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please check the endpoint of your graph api. It is `/beta` or `/v1.0`? And follow this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks).

Comment: @PamelaPeng it's /v1.0

Comment: @PamelaPeng I have followed all the steps in the document, I created a subscription, and got the first notification in which I validate the token, but when I update or delete a user I got nothing !

Answer (score 5):

[Per the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks-with-resource-data):

> Currently, the Microsoft Teams chatMessage as well as the Microsoft Teams presence (preview) resources supports change notifications that include resource data.

You will have to remove "includeResourceData"